# Need to search record with missing one value in column out of multiple record for the same date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have below sample data in mysql db

```
SC_ID   PAY_TY  PAY_SB_TY FY      PAY_DT       AMOUNT
S01     CASH              2014    12302014     142
S01     CREDIT  AE        2014    12302014     150
S01     CREDIT  Debit     2014    12302014     11
S01     Debit   DEBIT     2014    12302014     10
S01     CREDIT  visa      2014    12302014     23
S01     CREDIT  visa New  2014    12302014     12.5
```

these are record for one date 30 dec 2014, I need to find the date where there is no record for 'visa'
i.e. all rows are present but PAY_SB_TY='visa' is not present.

Please suggest how to do

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a where not exists clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tbl
   WHERE Pay_SB_Ty='Visa'
   AND Pay_Dt = t.Pay_Dt)
```